# How do I change public key policies programmatically?

Tags: powershell, security, group-policy

In order to automate the deployment of a certain service's installation, I'm trying to change the **Certificate Path Validation Settings** in PowerShell (any other programmatic method will do just as well). Specifically, I need to change the **Network Retrieval** settings (automatic update, override timeout settings, disallowing issuer certificate retrieval, etc.).

I know how to do this manually, using **secpol.msc**, but I need to automate this.

I tried to export the security configuration with **secedit.exe**, but either it doesn't contain the information that I need to modify, or I don't know how to identify it.

Does someone know how to get/modify these specific settings?

Comment: If whoever decided to down-vote this question would have the decency to explain what is wrong with this question, that would be really nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my solution - there is this tool called  [LGPO.EXE](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/), that can help import, export, and edit the Certificate Path Validation Settings programmatically. Use of this will still require a restart to get the changes to apply, but at least it is now possible.

Comment: How did you configure Network Retrieval settings with LGPO.exe? Could you explain more? Is there any file to edit for that settings? I would appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this exact issue right now.  [This page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848636.aspx) could be a valuable resource for you.  If you can download modules at work, that should do the trick for you (depending on what you need).  Unfortunately I can't, so I'm still looking for an answer to your question.

I've been hacking at this all day and have made a bit of progress.  These policies are found in the HKEY_USERS registry.  The below code successfully changed my AIA retrieval setting.  I'm still looking for where the other settings are in the registry.

```
set-location registry::\"HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1334943887-574888862-474100395-22132\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{D2FEBD75-F5EE-4C41-81A3-F95E12FFA66D}Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\ChainEngine\Config"
$path= (get-location).path

set-itemproperty -path $path -name options -value 2
```

Comment: What does the "options -value 2" mean? Does it enable the option? To enable, which value should be used?

Comment: It sets that key to the value associated with 2, that may be different on your system. I'm no registry expert, so take my advice with a grain of salt. My strategy was to take a text snapshot of the registry, use the UI to change the setting manually, take another snapshot, then compare. Make the change back and forth a couple times to make sure it's the right one, then try in Powershell. Always backup your system before hacking in the registry like this.